# VBA: Creating variable blocks with levels

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am a beginner in Excel VBA programming with 15 days of experience, I have worked with VBA using the macro recording functionality and am pretty comfortable withit.

I have a worksheet consisting of the following columns: Level,Id,Work-Product,Start,End

Level column consists of the Levels 1,2,3,4 and the other consists of random data. So, basically Level 1 would consist of:

```
   Level    ID  Work Product    Start       End
    1       A1  ABCD            1.1.2011    1.1.2013
```

Similarly for levels 2,3 and 4 consists of some data. Now, my task is to create a variable block which would look something like this:

```
'First Block Borders
'
    Range("O12:V13,O14:V14,O15:V15,O16:V16,O17:V17").Select
    Selection.BorderAround ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic
```

'Working for merge loop for first block

Dim row As Long

```
For row = 12 To 17
    If row = 12 Then
        Range(Cells(row, 15), Cells(row + 1, 22)).Merge
        row = row + 1
    Else
        Range(Cells(row, 15), Cells(17, 22)).Select
        Selection.Merge True
        Exit For
    End If
Next row
```

Now, I have 2 issues:

The first problem with this is that the block which is created here is a fixed block and I want it to be flexible so that if any one wants that he just needs only the first 4 columns then he is able to do it with the similar outline or if he wants to add another level it is also possible and the program automatically creates another level or similarly adds another line in the block if the user adds a new column.

The second problem is with the levels, I want to set the levels automatically using a loop so that after looking at the number of levels the program automatically creates the blocks with the content.

I have thoroughly searched all the forum posts and the internet for the answer but I am unable to automate this. My drawback is that I am still in the learning phase and I know the task above would require some experience and some amount of non-macro related coding.

Could anyone of you help me with this task, I would be highly grateful.

Thanks

---

Thanks for replying and sorry if my problem was not correctly understood. I will try to make it clearer now.

There are 2 worksheets worksheet 1 consists of the Data_Model which is like this:

```
Level  ID     Start         End             PT

1      A1     01.10.2012    30.09.2013  271.39
2      A1.1   01.10.2012    30.09.2013  83
3      A1.2   01.10.2012    30.09.2013  125.89
```

The Second worksheet would consist of data from this sheet but in a different form. Its a WBS (Work Breakdown Structure) Tree. The example of the block which I posted above is the estimated size which I imagined the block would be. Now, I have already made the WBS tree, but I got the requirement all wrong as I made it fixed "create borders around data in columns "O" and "V"".

What I want to achieve here is that programatically, if I run this VBA script it should do the following:

1. Create a box (similar to the dimensions as I put in the first post) in the secons worksheet.
2. If the user later inserts a new column in the first worksheet the script should allow the updation of the box according to the addition and deletion of the columns in the first workseet.
3. The Levels 2,3,4,5 should fall below the first block and should also consist of the functionality that if a user inserts a new row with a new level in the 1st worksheet then it should automatically add a new block with the required dimensions in the second worksheet.

   ---

The below code I worked on is more or less hard-coded and does not consists of the above functionality, but if you run that then you might have an idea what I am talking about.

---

```
Option Explicit


Sub Sixth_Tree()


'First Block Borders
'
Range("EH12:EO13,EH14:EO14,EH15:EO15,EH16:EO16,EH17:EO17").Select
Selection.BorderAround ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic


'Merge First Borders


' Range(Cells(12, 15), Cells(13, 22)).Merge
' Range(Cells(14, 15), Cells(17, 22)).Merge True



'Working for loop for first block


'Dim row As Long
'
'For row = 12 To 17
' If row = 12 Then
' Range(Cells(row, 15), Cells(row + 1, 22)).Merge
' row = row + 1
' Else
' Range(Cells(row, 15), Cells(17, 22)).Select
' Selection.Merge True
' Exit For
' End If
'Next row

'Test For loop for multiple blocks merge


'Dim row As Long
' For row = 12 And 20 And 26 And 34 And 41 To 46
' If row = 12 And 20 And 26 And 34 And 41 Then
' Range(Cells(row, 15), Cells(row + 1, 22)).Merge
' row = row + 1
' Else
' Range(Cells(row, 15), Cells(17, 22)).Select
' Selection.Merge True
' Exit For
' End If
'Next row


'Merge 1st block For Loop


Dim irow As Long, icol As Long
icol = 138
For irow = 12 To 17


If irow = 12 Then
Range(Cells(irow, 138), Cells(irow + 1, 145)).Merge
irow = irow + 1


Else
Range(Cells(irow, 138), Cells(17, 145)).Select
Selection.Merge True
Exit For
End If


Next irow


'Second block Borders


Range("EJ20:EQ21,EJ22:EQ22,EJ23:EQ23,EJ24:EQ24,EJ25:EQ25").Select
Selection.BorderAround ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic

'Merge 2nd block For Loop


icol = 140
For irow = 20 To 25


If irow = 20 Then
Range(Cells(irow, 140), Cells(irow + 1, 147)).Merge
irow = irow + 1


Else
Range(Cells(irow, 140), Cells(25, 147)).Select
Selection.Merge True
Exit For
End If


Next irow

'Merge second Borders


Range(Cells(20, 17), Cells(21, 24)).Merge
Range(Cells(22, 17), Cells(25, 24)).Merge True


'Third block Borders


Range("EJ27:EQ28,EJ29:EQ29,EJ30:EQ30,EJ31:EQ31,EJ32:EQ32").Select
Selection.BorderAround ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic

'Merge 3rd block For Loop


icol = 140
For irow = 27 To 32


If irow = 27 Then
Range(Cells(irow, 140), Cells(irow + 1, 147)).Merge
irow = irow + 1


Else
Range(Cells(irow, 140), Cells(32, 147)).Select
Selection.Merge True
Exit For
End If


Next irow


'Merge Third Borders


Range(Cells(27, 17), Cells(28, 24)).Merge
Range(Cells(29, 17), Cells(32, 24)).Merge True

'Fourth block Borders


Range("EJ34:EQ35,EJ36:EQ36,EJ37:EQ37,EJ38:EQ38,EJ39:EQ39").Select
Selection.BorderAround ColorIndex:=xlColorIndexAutomatic

'Merge 4th block For Loop


icol = 140
For irow = 34 To 39


If irow = 34 Then
Range(Cells(irow, 140), Cells(irow + 1, 147)).Merge
irow = irow + 1


Else
Range(Cells(irow, 140), Cells(39, 147)).Select
Selection.Merge True
Exit For
End If


Next irow


'Merge Fourth Borders


Range(Cells(34, 17), Cells(35, 24)).Merge
Range(Cells(36, 17), Cells(39, 24)).Merge True


'Connecting Lines
'
Range("EI18:EI34").Select
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With


Range("EI20, EI27, EI34").Select
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With


'Color


' Range("O12:V13,Q20:X21,Q27:X28,Q34:X35,Q41:X42").Select
' With Selection.Interior
' .Pattern = xlSolid
' .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
' .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
' End With
'
' Range("O14:V14,Q22:X22,Q29:X29,Q36:X36,Q43:X43").Select
' With Selection.Interior
' .Pattern = xlSolid
' .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
' .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
' End With
'
' Range("O17:V17,Q25:X25,Q32:X32,Q39:X39,Q46:X46").Select
' With Selection.Interior
' .Pattern = xlSolid
' .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
' .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
' End With
'
'Copying from the Data_Model and alignment


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Sheets("Data_Model")
.Range("C77").Copy Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("EH12:EO13")
.Range("C78").Copy Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("EJ20:EQ21")
.Range("C79").Copy Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("EJ27:EQ28")
.Range("C80").Copy Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("EJ34:EQ35")
End With
'
''Hard Coding the the 4 sub-cells in the block
'
' Dim irow As Long, irow1 As Long, icol As Long
'
' icol = 15
' For irow = 14 To 22 Step 8
' Cells(irow, icol).Value = "Aufwand/Summe: "
' Cells(irow + 1, icol).Value = "Start: "
' Cells(irow + 2, icol).Value = "Ende: "
' Cells(irow + 3, icol).Value = "Verantw: "
' icol = 17
' For irow1 = 29 To 46 Step 7
' Cells(irow1, icol).Value = "Aufwand/Summe: "
' Cells(irow1 + 1, icol).Value = "Aufwand/Summe: "
' Cells(irow1 + 1, icol).Value = "Start: "
' Cells(irow1 + 2, icol).Value = "Ende: "
' Cells(irow1 + 3, icol).Value = "Verantw: "
' icol = 17
' Next irow1
' Next irow
'
''Wrap and Font for all
'
' With Range("O12:V13,Q20:X21,Q27:X28,Q34:X35,Q41:X42,O14:V14,O15:V15,O16:V16," & _
' "O17:V17,Q41:X42,Q22:X22,Q23:X23,Q24:X24,Q25:X25,Q30:X30,Q31:X31,Q32:X32," & _
' "Q38:X38,Q39:X39,Q41:X42,Q46:X46,Q29:X29,Q36:X36,Q43:X43,Q37:X37,Q44:X44,Q45:X45")
' .WrapText = True
' .Name = "TKTypeRegular"
' .Font.Size = 9
' .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
' End With

End Sub
```

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to get done here. Based on what I can understand is you have this line of code:

```
Range("O12:V13,O14:V14,O15:V15,O16:V16,O17:V17").Select
```

which you got from recording a macro. Instead of being limited to the "O" and "V" column you want to be able to select other columns and ranges.

Comment: I have added some additinal details in my above question. I hope it makes things clearer.

Comment: If you want you can send me your file and I will take a look at it